# Why isn't the inline height value being updated after using setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal: Dynamically increase the value of the height of the textarea element after text is entered/pasted in. The the value of height should match that of the textarea's scrollHeight after it surpasses clientHeight.

Issue: The style property continues reflecting the initial state of height, which is inherit.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Textarea extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            height: 'inherit'
        };

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
    }

    handleKeyUp = (event) => {
        if (event.target.scrollHeight > event.target.clientHeight) {
            let newHeight = `${event.target.scrollHeight}px`;
            this.setState({
                height: newHeight
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <div className="content_wrap">
                <textarea
                    id="json-textarea"
                    className="content_textarea"
                    onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
                    style={this.state}

                ></textarea>                        
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: does your code go inside the if statement at all? because in the if condition, you are using `event.scrollHeight` and the line below you are using `event.target.scrollHeight` ... only one of them can be correct.

Comment: Thank you for this; you were correct. While the problem isn't solved as of yet, I can confirm the code is now going inside the if statement thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to point state.height and onKeyUp you have to pass function.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export class Textarea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      height: "inherit",
    };

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyUp = (event) => {
    if (event.scrollHeight > event.clientHeight) {
      let newHeight = `${event.target.scrollHeight}px`;
      this.setState({
        height: newHeight,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="content_wrap">
        <textarea
          id="json-textarea"
          className="content_textarea"
          onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} // Change here
          style={this.state} // Change here
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I implemented your suggestions, which are surely correct, but I am now running into a new error. The new error is "The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string."

Comment: @MrSandman98765 style expects object not the string  `style={this.state}` work.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to point the `height` properties in your state

```
<textarea
    id="json-textarea"
    className="content_textarea"
    onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp(this)}
    style={this.state.height}
>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was certainly part of the problem, and I've edited my code to reflect your suggestion. Unfortunately, I am still running into an issue as mentioned in my reply to another commenter.

Comment: To clarify, it appears pointing to the height property wasn't the solution after all. It led to an error that I mention in a reply to another commenter. Still appreciate the help, though!